# Raspberry crontab python script at boot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cron, boot

I've been trying to launch a python script at the boot of the Rpi, but everything I've tried until now did not work.

The script is some version of this : https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/temperature-log/worksheet/ :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
from subprocess import check_output
from re import findall
from time import sleep, strftime, time

def get_temp():
    temp = check_output(["vcgencmd","measure_temp"]).decode("UTF-8")
    temp = float(findall("\d+\.\d+",temp)[0])
    return(temp)

while True:
    log=open("cpu_temp.txt","a")
    temp = get_temp()
    log.write("{0} {1}".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),str(temp))+" degreeC\r\n")
    sleep(60)  
    log.close()
```

It works fine on its own. I tried editing crontab, with and without the absolute path to Python, as well as editing /etc/rc.local

I know it doesn't work, because it should create a text file and edit it each minute, and it's not created at boot. I have other commands in crontab and rc.local that are working.

Need some help please !

Comment: `crontab` may run with different privileges, in different environment and in different folder - you may need to use full path for created file.

Comment: Try with an absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

If your script is located at `/home/pi/tempcheck.py` the you should edit crontab with

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and append the line

```
@reboot python /home/pi/tempcheck.py &
```

then save and exit.

Further details can be found at http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/07/running-a-python-script-at-boot-using-cron/

You can check it is running with

```
ps aux | grep tempcheck.py
```

Note that if you edit root's crontab, the python process will be run as root. So you should use absolute filenames in the python script:

```
log=open("/home/pi/cpu_temp.txt","a")
```

Comment: I didn't thought of adding the absolute path in the script itself, it's working now. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo crontab -e

@reboot /usr/bin/python /path/to/file/script.py
```

`/path/to/file/script.py` would probably be something like `/home/username/script.py`

If it still doesn't work you can try giving it execute permission with this:

```
chmod a+x script.py
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call your script in the `~/.bashrc` file. It will be called at boot or terminal opening.

Just write :

```
python /path/to/your/script.py
```

At the end of the .bashrc file.

Comment: this is not what he asks

Comment: "I've been trying to launch a python script at the boot of the Rpi" --> yes, that is exactly what he asked.

Comment: at the boot, not at terminal opening